# How to create class with collection of values using generator method in javascript/ ecmascript 6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here for the Service class I like to create a default iterator. I need to make service iterable but I can not think further. I believe I need to use *Symbol.iterator but don't know how to use

```
class Service {

  constructor() {
      this.link = [];
  }

}

var service = new Service();
service.link.push(1);
service.link.push(2);
service.link.push(3);

for (let x of service) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just define `*[Symbol.iterator]() {` on the class

```js
class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.link = [];
  }
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.link.length; i++)
      yield this.link[i];
  }
}
var service = new Service();
service.link.push(1);
service.link.push(2);
service.link.push(3);
for (const x of service) {
  console.log(x);
}
```